# How to make eclipse auto fill android:text not android:text=""

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I program android apps and i have one annoying feature in eclipse that i don't know how to turn off. I want eclipse to auto fill `android:textStyle` and give me more options like "bold", "italic" and not auto fill `android:textStyle=""` without giving me option to choose like mentioned above. 
 Please be specific and repply **ASVP**. Please give me instructions like go to file->open... and i have eclipse 4.2.1 with ADT `Version: 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395` 
 **THANKS**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The auto fill you are describing is called Content Assist. You don't need to change the way it works, you simply need to learn more about it: You can trigger this method manually by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> at any time.

On a new line in your View's XML type: `textst` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to get:

```
    android:textStyle=""
```

While the cursor is still *between* the quote marks press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> again to see the list of "normal", "bold", "italic".

*Also* you can quickly add more styles by using `|` symbol, for example `android:textStyle="bold|"`, simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to another say "italic"...

```
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
```

---

**Added from comments**
I don't know much about customizing Content Assist, but to reach its XML settings go to:

**Window** -> **Preferences** and then **XML** -> **XML Files** -> **Editor** -> **Content Assist**

You can find various settings here, including choosing the delay and prompt characters. If you use `<a:="|` this will cover the *beginning* of almost every line in an Android XML file. But you might want to be comprehensive by listing *every* character `aAbBcC` (etc) to open the Content Assist as much as possible...

Also you can make keyboard buttons with the HTML keyboard tag, for instance I made <kbd>Bonzai!</kbd> with:

```
 <kbd>Bonzai!</kbd>
```

Comment: That works for me but... can it be auto and how do you intert keys into post

Comment: Thanks a lot sorry i can't wote up i am dont have privilege that high but anyway +1!

Comment: No trouble. Come back to upvote later when you have 15+ reputation. :)